# VBA Looping through an array but getting runtime error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

I have some experience with C/PHP but am not that fluent in VBA. I have a list of 30 items in excel, each with particular specs and I am just going down the list, comparing each item's specs pairwise against those below it. If there's a match, I put a 1 in the column next to the item. But I'm getting a runtime error 9 subscript out of range (I don't think I'm exceeding line 30 or column 5 at any point).  It occurs at the line where I check if the conditions are fulfilled:

```
If data(rowi, 1) = data(rowj, 1) And data(rowi, 2) = data(rowj, 2) And Abs(data(rowi, 5) = data(rowj, 5)) = 2 Then
```

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim rowi As Integer
    Dim rowj As Integer
    
    data = Range("B2:F31").Value
        For rowi = 0 To 28
        For rowj = rowi + 1 To 29
            If data(rowi, 1) = data(rowj, 1) And data(rowi, 2) = data(rowj, 2) And Abs(data(rowi, 5) = data(rowj, 5)) = 2 Then
                    Cells(rowi, 11).Value = 1
            End If
        Next rowj
    Next rowi
End Sub
```

Comment: `data` is a one-based array

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the input, somehow I was under the impression that VBA array indexing defaults to 0. So I made rowi start from 1 instead of 0, that got rid of the error but I'm not showing any matches when visually I can see there are a couple.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this condition?  `Abs(data(rowi, 5) = data(rowj, 5)) = 2`

Comment: Column 5 contains product ratings, I'm looking for products which have the same price/specs (columns 1/2) but which differ in ratings by 2 on a Likert scale.

Comment: Okay, so maybe you meant to subtract and take the absolute value and compare that to 2.  Right now you are checking if data(rowi, 5) is equal to data(rowj, 5) and taking the absolute value of true or false.

Comment: Of course you're right! That was dumb of me, I've been staring at it for too long @_@. Thanks a lot! But I still don't get why the array index defaulted to 1 and not 0, documentation says otherwise: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays

Comment: Some light reading about why range objects do 1-base https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7657804b-987e-4465-b591-4cd7a9072ec0/reading-an-excel-range-into-object-1-based?forum=vsto

Comment: In simple word, a new array defined by Dim starts from 0, a variant array fetchs from range starts from 1.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and @Abel Wong. ALL the documentation on microsoft.com have 0 as the default value. Had I known it would have saved me hours of frustration.  Thanks to Bill Gates too  >:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Find Matches Below

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("B2:F31")
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim rOffset As Long: rOffset = rg.Row - 1
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim ri As Long
    Dim rj As Long
    
    For ri = 1 To rCount - 1
        For rj = ri + 1 To rCount
            If Data(ri, 1) = Data(rj, 1) _
                    And Data(ri, 2) = Data(rj, 2) _
                    And Abs(Data(ri, 5) - Data(rj, 5)) = 2 Then
                ws.Cells(ri + rOffset, 11).Value = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rj
    Next ri

End Sub
```